# Get the number of trees used for a GBM with early stopping

Tags: python, h2o, hyperparameters

I trained a GBM in h2o using early stopping and setting `ntrees=10000`. I want to retrieve the number of trees are actually in the model. But if I called `model.params['ntrees']` (where `model` is the best model from a gridsearch) I get

```
{'default': 50, 'actual': 10000}
```

where the `10000` is the parameter I set during training but not the actual number of trees that ended up in the model.

If I call `model.score_history()` then i can see that early stopping kicked in at `280` trees. But surely there is a more direct way to find out the actual number of trees in the model than this hack:

```
best_model.score_history()['number_of_trees'].max()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently isn't a clean way to do this. An alternative method, which doesn't require calculating a max but is still clunk to do is `model.summary()['number_of_trees'][0]` if you want the number, `model.summary()['number_of_trees']` if you want the number in a list. Or just `model.summary()` if you just want to see the number.

Comment: Thanks. Weird that it's not saved in the `params` dictionary though, is this by design?